# How to count based on multiple columns in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have columns in a table like this:

```
race  | active
===============
asian | false
black | true 
asian | false
white | true 
asian | false
black | false
asian | false
white | false
asian | false
black | true 
black | true 
asian | false
white | true 
asian | false
black | false
```

I need to calculate the count like

```
 white-active : 2
 asian-active : 
 black-active : 
 asian-inactive : 
 white-inactive : 
 black-inactive :
```

How can I achieve this in SQL Server 2008?

Comment: hint: look up 'group by'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
SELECT race + '-active : ' + CAST(count(active) OVER(PARTITION BY race) AS VARCHAR) output
FROM Your_Table WHERE active='true'
union all
SELECT race + '-inactive : ' + CAST(count(active) OVER(PARTITION BY race) AS VARCHAR) output
FROM Your_Table WHERE active='false'
```

Comment: thanks man... exactly what i was looking for ...

Answer (score 1):

can try this

```
select race||'-active'||' : '||count(active) as output
from table
where active='true'
group by race
union all
select race||'-inactive'||' : '||count(active) as output 
from table
where active='false'
group by race
```

Comment: You could remove the redundant `FROM ... WHERE ... GROUP BY` section if you use `CASE`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments:

```
SELECT race, active, COUNT(*)
FROM t
GROUP BY race, active;
```

Or if you really need that exact string output:

```
SELECT
    race || '-' || 
    case when active = 'true' then 'active' else 'inactive' end || 
    ' : ' || COUNT(*)
FROM t
GROUP BY race, active;
```